# TextView click disabled and hidden but still click is working- Android

Tags: android, textview, onclicklistener, picasso

I have an `ImageView` and a `TextView` over it displaying "View Album". I am loading an image inside this `ImageView` using `Picasso`. I want to hide this `TextView` and disable its click until the image is loaded in `ImageView`.If image is not downloaded, then I hide the `TextView` or else `TextView` is shown and redirects to another screen when clicked. I tried using

```
                     <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtViewAlbum"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="25dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
                            android:background="#435FA7"
                            android:clickable="false"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:paddingRight="4dp"
                            android:text="View Album"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="12sp"
                            android:visibility="gone" />
```

and

```
    txtViewAlbum = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtViewAlbum);
    eventImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgDetail);
    txtViewAlbum.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    eventImage.setClickable(false);
    txtViewAlbum.setClickable(false);`
```

at the first place.

And image loading done using:

```
Picasso picasso = Picasso.with(getActivity());
    picasso.setDebugging(true);
    picasso.setIndicatorsEnabled(false);
    picasso.load(downloadPath + thumbImg).placeholder(R.drawable.no_image)
            .error(R.drawable.no_image).into(eventImage, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    txtViewAlbum.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    eventImage.setClickable(true);
                    txtViewAlbum.setClickable(true);

                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {
                    Log.d("Error...", "picasso load error");
                    Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(R.drawable.no_image)
                            .into(eventImage);
                    txtViewAlbum.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    eventImage.setClickable(false);
                    txtViewAlbum.setClickable(false);
                }
            });
```

But the `TextView` click is working for like 2-3 seconds until the image is loaded. I want to disable it. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried setEnabled(false)?

Comment: yes. that isn't working either

Comment: disable and hide before loading image

Comment: @StepanMaksymov like how?

Comment: check answer below

Comment: for disabling clicks I think you can pass null into setOnclickListener I think. Like mTextView.setOnclickListener(null)

Comment: Try `textView.setKeyListener(null); // disable keyboard`

Comment: @Jas i think problem with url .Have check url using Logs.

Answer (score 0):

try to use something like this:

```
mTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // here disable and hide your view
                }
            });
            // here load your image with on error loading maybe restore views to be visible again
        }
    });
```